# tutorial to create e-book read application - epub file formate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, epub

I am making an application of e book reading, in that i want to perform some operations like change text color, font, select a text etc.

I come to know that iphone os 4.0 and ipad are now supporting epub file formate, but I am not able to know how to create such kind of application. If any one knows how to create such applications please let me know.

thanks in advance

Here are some links regarding e-pub

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB

http://code.google.com/p/epub-tools/

Comment: ok thanks brad. let me check all this things.

Comment: Right now I am able to read the epub files and also showing the same in the webview but there are still many things which can be performed using such kind files in the iphone. As iBook provides lot many things, So any other and newer ways to create the similar applications, or the manner in which such applications can be created.

Comment: It looks like the text font and colour,might be controlled from a .css file, which is declared in the content.opf file. Is it possible that the .css is updated when a epub app changes the font or colour.

Comment: @BradLarson redeem yourself.

Comment: @Will - Since you asked nicely. Wish I could search for all these old, expired close votes.

Comment: @BradLarson: Hah!  You have deleted your shame!

Comment: this question is about creating while the other one is about Reading there is a clear difference i think..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a full tutorial for creating [mobi](http://www.katiebooks.ca/tutorials.html?ifrm_4=mobi.html) and [epubs](http://www.katiebooks.ca/tutorials.html?ifrm_4=epub.html) on www.katiebooks.ca.

Comment: can you check the links now please.

Comment: links are not working

Answer (score 1):

Its not a tutorial, but you might want to use the [source-code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~kovid/calibre/trunk/files/head:/src/calibre/ebooks/epub/) of [Calibre's](http://calibre-ebook.com/about) ebook viewer component as a reference (note that Calibre is GPL licensed).

Otherwise, given that ePub is a zipped xml format, I'd **get a copy of the [spec](http://www.idpf.org/specs.htm)** and then **start learning about [xml parsing in python](http://diveintopython.net/xml_processing/)**.