# How can create and read ePub file programmatically in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, epub

I want to create and read ePub file using some information programmatically in iPhone. Please help me how can create and read ePub file.

Comment: check this link...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193294/tutorial-to-create-e-book-read-application-epub-file-formate?rq=1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388467/reading-epub-format?rq=1

:)

Comment: I have done parsing epub but unable to create epub file through code .thanks a lot

Comment: any update on this?? have you found a way to create e-pubs the easy way?

Answer (score 0):

Get this epub-checker app for generating epub file easy way

http://www.pagina-online.de/produkte/epub-checker/